# Is this a function or variable definition in c++ code?

Tags: c++

I am reading a piece of c++ code in which ids, curi and len are integer, content are string.  I don't understand what's match_word() part. Is it a function or variable? I can't find its definition in all header files.

```
 if(-1!=ids) 
          {
            len = ids - curi;
            string match_word(content, curi, len);
            bool rejudge = false;
            ...
          }
```

Comment: For future questions, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People often forget the _minimal_ part. In this case, we clearly don't need the `if` statement, or `rejudge`, or `ids` - or much of the code; names like `content`, `len` and `curi` could be renamed to `string str; int a, b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [std::string documentation](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```
string match_word(content, curi, len);
```

This is/uses a **substring constructor** which

> Copies the portion of content that begins at the character position curi and spans len characters (or until the end of content, if either content is too short or if len is string::npos).

So for example

```
std::string s = "Hello World";
string match_word(s, 2, 7);
std::cout<<match_word<<std::endl; //prints llo Wor
```

The above will print `llo Wor`

Now coming to your question:

> Is this a function or variable definition in c++ code?

Basically this is a variable definition using the substring constructor. So in your case `match_word` is a variable of type `std::string`.

Comment: More generally the syntax seen here is constructor initialization.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
string match_word(content, curi, len);
```

`match_word` is a string. This is a declaration. Looks like you want to call this constructor:

```cpp
string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos);
```

Here is an example from [cplusplus](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string s0 ("Initial string");
    std::string s3 (s0, 8, 3);
    std::cout << s3;
}
```

This will print:

```
str
```